# Access Query Limit From Another Query

Tags: ms-access, limit

I am trying to get a query to populate claims that are above an upper limit that is specified in another query. The claims from query 1 and the upper limit in query 2 are related by part numbers. the below pictures will give a better visual rep.

[image]

[image]

Edit:If the claim field for month is less than the upper limit then I don't want it show in the query, but each upper limit is different for each part number.

Comment: Perhaps  join data on PartNo and filter Claims>=UpperLimit. Edit question to show desired output.

Comment: Do you want to just show Parts where the total claims for a month exceeds the limit? As @June7 said, please show us the output that you expect in order for anybody to be able to answer without guessing.

Comment: The output I was describing is what @mazoula is showing in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
[image]

[image]

Here is the sql:

```
SELECT Claims.PartNo, Month([Claims].[ProdYM]) AS [Month], Year([Claims].[ProdYM]) AS [Year], Sum(Claims.Claims) AS SumOfClaims
FROM UpperLimits INNER JOIN Claims ON UpperLimits.PartNO = Claims.PartNo
GROUP BY Claims.PartNo, Month([Claims].[ProdYM]), Year([Claims].[ProdYM])
HAVING (((Sum(Claims.Claims))>=Max([UpperLimits].[UpperLimit])));
```

Result:

[image]
this is a totals query so upper limit needs to have a summary function.  Max was easiest to find but first and last will work if you find them.

Comment: When I try the same setup on my database the `>=Max([UpperLimits].[Upperlimit])`  part is throwing an invalid operator error. I changed the only thing I changed was the table name due to having a different name in my database.

Comment: Two suggestions.  first you have enough information to duplicate my answer in an independent database.  It is a 20 minute pain but it is practice.  I suspect max will work there.  What I think is this is an access bug caused by one of your queries being complicated.  if that is the case you can also test that by applying the following fix:  copy your query(s) and turn the copy(s) into a make table query.  then run the solution on those tables.

Comment: a less diagnostic fix that only adds one more query is divide and conquor.  split my solution into two simpler queries so access doesn't bug.  for instance delete the criteria  under SumClaims and add the upperlimit column(UL) to the query (put your choice of first, last, max in the total row of UL). So I called the new column UL and the new query EC2.  You can make EC2 a make table query if EC3 still bugs.  Next make another query called EC3 based on EC2 and select all members of EC2 then add the now simpler criteria (<= EC2.UL under SumofClaims.

Comment: I made the qry into the table and it worked. Thank you so much!